# makefile to run the code it compiles

Tags: c++, makefile

If I have a code that will run, call it `main.cpp`, and the executable is `r.exe`, then I write a makefile with the following target:

```
compile: 
    g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o r
```

The executable, `r.exe` takes as two arguments `i.txt`, `o.txt`.  How do I add a second target to the makefile such that I can run the following command, and see the program execute:

```
make run i.txt o.txt
```

---

I have tried adding a second target to the makefile:

```
run:
    r.exe $1 $2
```

for instance, but make declares: "'r' is up to date" and "nothing to be done for 'i.txt', ... etc."

I have also tried searching for a while now, but 'make', 'run' and 'variables' or 'arguments' have, essentially, a search firewall of unrelated content.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing whether there is a way to do this with make alone, but for me it makes more sense to use a bash script.

Comment: I suggest you also try using something cross-platform and more powerful like CMake. As for the problem, simply have your IDE run it after compiling (Visual Studio has such an option).

Comment: @synchronizer yeah I am still new to c++.  The reqs for this situation are that the following commands must be run, verbatim: `make compile` and then `make run i.txt o.txt`  (would I be able to put a bash file in there?)

Comment: @synchronizer or maybe the requirement is an error, given the answer below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass arguments to `make` like that. The command `make run i.txt o.txt` would attempt to build the rules `run`, `i.txt`, and `o.txt`.

What you could instead to is use a variable:

```
run:
    r.exe ${ARGS}

make run ARGS="i.txt o.txt"
```

---

Side-note, rules should make the files that they say they do. So you really would want your compile rule to look like:

```
r.exe : main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 $^ -o $@

compile : r.exe
.PHONY  : compile
```